# What is the plural form of musical score?

Tags: grammar, orthography

The title of a Spotify playlist from Disney is "Disney Score To Study To". The name surprised me because I would have thought it would be titled "Disney Scores To Study To". Seeing as this is an official playlist from Disney, I would like to think they thought about the grammar.

This is a link to the playlist for reference:
https://open.spotify.com/playlist/49NljZ2KE0JrAz0NapcDVt?si=WGA4oiO2T1WgO6jIhGCf1Qr

Comment: The singular is perhaps defensible here if you consider this playlist a new ‘score’ for the fictional ‘movie’ that is your studies – but then the subtitle is “Escape distraction **with score** from your favorite Disney movies”, which is just plain and unequivocally ungrammatical (highlighted). This was clearly made by a non-native speaker with little grasp of English grammar.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: It is an interesting concept to consider a playlist as a cohesive musical piece that can collectively be referred to as a "score". However, I agree that in this particular case, it's probably just a matter of someone using poor grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plural of *score* is *scores*.

The question is, should this *score* have been plural.

> **score**
>
> 6 a : the copy of a musical composition in written or printed notation
>
> b : a musical composition
> *specifically* : the music for a movie or theatrical production

It seems that whoever titled that playlist intended the phrase to mean *this collection of songs is the score for your study session* (as if your study session were a film).

In any case, *scores* would be incorrect. One single (film) score is made up of multiple tracks. Each track is not a score, so that playlist does not include multiple scores (it may contain pieces from multiple scores).

Comment: I suppose it'd be technically more correct to say "Disney score pieces" rather than "Disney scores", but in practical usage, I don't think anyone expects to hear the entire score for any one movie. Likewise, if I put on a playlist of movie soundtracks, I don't expect to hear 1-3 hours of music from a single movie before moving to the next. To use the plural "scores" in this case is imprecise, but is concise and easily understood.